# Understanding the parallelism of FPGAs

Tags: fpga

I am having a bit of a problem understanding the benefits of FPGAs for parallel processing. Everybody says it is parallel, but It looks to me like it is not truly parallel. Let's see this example:

I have a data signal coming on some pins, at 1 bit per clock cycle. The FPGA will receive this data and since it has the data already inside the integrated circuit it can start processing it right away. But this is called serial processing, not parallel. If the FPGA waits for the data to accumulate, to later process it in parallel, then we can say FPGA processing is truly parallel but what is the benefit of waiting for the data to arrive in large quantities, we will just lose time, for example, if we wait for 8-bit data, we will lose 7 cycles. So where is the benefit of parallelism of FPGAs?? I can't get it.

It would be parallel if the data were coming in parallel, like when you use the old DB-25 Parallel Port connector. However, this technology became obsolete since parallel ports can not support high speeds. Today's USB standard is serial, Ethernet is serial, so .... where is the parallelism??

Comment: what makes you think that serial data streams can't be processed in parallel? just because data arrives in a serial fashion doesn't "parallelism" can't be applied after wards.

Comment: "if we wait for 8 bit data , we will lose 7 cycles",,, ,and if the processing step takes 100,000 cycles, then the 7 cycle delay to collect the data first gets lost in the noise (if you even choose to do it... it's perfectly possible to have some of your parallel blocks making progress while the others are still waiting for input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parallelism comes in if you have data that arrives in chunks, and the chunks arrive faster than they can be processed, and the chunks can be processed individually. Rather than having to slow-down the data sender, an FPGA allows you to add more processing "blocks" so that the processing goes faster.

Example:
You receive data (serially or in parallel, doesn't matter) at 1MB/s in 50kB chunks, but your algorithm only allows 1 chunk to be processed per second. In an FPGA, you can wire up the "receiver" to distribute the chunks across 20 "processors", so now your sender can still send at full speed, and your receiver sees less overall lag.

Comment: Or, perhaps the most (in)famous example: Bitcoin. A single "input" (block) is distributed to all the miners, and every miner's goal is to be the first to find an "output" that matches Bitcoin's requirements. So, FPGA's are great for this, because from the single input block, they can work on dozens (hundreds? thousands‽ millions‽‽‽) of "outputs" simultaneously, and report the first acceptable one they find back to the Blockchain, to get their mining reward.

Comment: or in other words, you are saying: the parallelism in FPGAs is exploited if  and only if the data can not be processed individually, but only in chunks.Then the level of parallelism achieved in the FPGA will be equal to the size of the chunk. If you have a chunk size = 1 bit, you have 0 grade of parallelism. If chunk size = 64 bits, you have grade of parallelism of 63. I am understanding you correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean by a "grade of parallelism", but it really isn't dependent on chunk size. In my specific example, it's a function of receive bandwidth vs. calculation bandwidth.

It's definitely not an "if and only if" scenario either, FPGA's are quite versatile. For example, you can use them for video data, where you have a single input stream, then the FPGA can isolate the red, green, and blue channels, and output a red, green, and blue video stream.

Answer (score 1):

Parallelism has several levels, which need to be understood if you want to under stand computer architectures. FPGAs are just a tool to build a "computer".

The levels are:

- **bit level:** multiple bits or datawords are processed in parallel.
  For example you can build adders of 8 bit, 32 bit or 4096 bit, which add two integer numbers in just one cycle
- **instruction level:** multiple instructions of one control flow are executed in parallel
   => pipelining, super scalar architecture
- **thread level**: multiple control flows are executed in paralell
  => multi threading, multi core, n-socket systems
- **application level**: execute multiple applications in parallel
  => multi processing
- **dataflow processing**: every thing in parallel :)

FPGAs can use each level to do everything in parallel.

Comment: You said I can build adders 4096 bits wide, but why would I wait for the remaining 4064 (4096-32) bits if I already have 32 bits inside the device. I can start my virtual sequential RISC (or whatever)  processor inside the FPGA to execute the addition instruction. But why would I create virtual processors inside the FPGA, if I can integrate multicore, ASIC-made faster real processors to do this addition by multithreading, not SIMDing ....??

Comment: If there's an ASIC already on the market that does what you need it to do, then use it! FPGA's certainly aren't the best device for every application, a RISC CPU can handle most workflows.
Consider the following scenario:
You have two arrays, A and B. Each array has 4,000 elements, and you want to perform A + B. On a RISC CPU, this involves 4,000 ADD operations (maybe less with SIMD), and those are cycles the CPU can't use for anything else. The FPGA can complete the above in 1 clock. The FPGA is also flexible, e.g. if array size increases, where an ASIC is generally not extensible.

Comment: Except for ASICs, an FPGA is always faster than a softcore or a CPU. Adding two 4096 bit integers can be done in an FPGA at (I guess) 100 MHz. A 32 bit CPU @ 3GHz with an optimal instruction set needs 128 cycles. So there is a frequency gap of 30. So the FPGA is 4 times faster. You are assuming data arrives in serial streams to the FPGA, that's mostly correct, but your bandwidth is not correct. Modern links like 10GbE or 400G Interlaken stream several hundred GBit/s to an FPGA. Sources are mostly networks or ultra fast ADCs....

Comment: ... FPGAs reach a aggregated I/O performance of several TBit/s. Which CPU could handle this? There are image processing algorithms that require >1 min computation time per FullHD frame on a CPU. An FPGA handles this computation in a fraction of a second achieving > 80 fps and uses only a fraction of the FPGA area. Why? Because it processes pixel groups in parallel, while results are already transfered to the host system, while another data stream (new frame) arrives in parallel. That's parallelism!